# Store JWT/authorization on the Client/Server side of application [JavaScript]

Tags: node.js, redis, frontend, backend

Right now I am using a JWT token to validate the user and on the client side I store it in cookies. On the server side, I just generate this token and send it to the client side.

As I have seen, there are several approaches where server side tokens / authorization are stored in redis. I don't understand why I would use this. Can you provide me with some use cases for this? And maybe I should store the client side token somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing JWT on the server with Redis gives you more control over how authentication/authorization works on your app.

Consider the logout process, ideally, it should invalidate a token, but JWT doesn't really give you an easy way to revoke a token.

The best bet is to have it stored somewhere (Redis) and when a logout request is received, the saved token is deleted.

[Redis](https://redis.io/commands/expire) is relatively fast, because of its cache feature, which basically allows you to save/retrieve the token in memory, and it also provides some cool features, one of which is to expire/self-delete a saved token after a set time.

Comment: Since most users don't actively "logout" I would suggest to store the "revoked" list of tokens in Redis and not the "active" list, this way only token that were actively revoked will be saved the rest will just expire

Comment: @Fortune Ekeruo thank you for explanation. i have one more question. How it should work? I mean what i should store in redis? What kind of user data?

Comment: There are several ways to do this. Basically, you only want to save the same token you generated and sent back to the client. Every time the client makes a request. you check whether the token exists in the cache before processing the request.  @GuyKorland proposed another approach.

Comment: @GuyKorland and Fortune Ekeruo  thanks for advices